# Redirect an event to an inner element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a special scenario where I need to capture key events on a higher level, and redirect them to a lower level. I'm trying to write code like this, but actually it seems like `jQuery` is dumbly using the exact same event object, so `target` is not changed, so `Maximum callstack size exceeded`...

```
$("#outer").on("keydown", function(evt) {
  if (evt.target !== $("#inner")[0] && !$.contains($("#inner")[0], evt.target)) {
    $("#inner").trigger(evt);
  }
});
```

With a sample markup

```
<div id="#outer">
  <div id="#inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

What is the proper way to *redirect* an event to another element? I could of course manually "hack" the `target`, but is it safe?

I'm working on a plugin which dynamically shows a menu as a popup or as a modal based on screen size. If I have a modal, I need this key redirection. The consumer should not know about wether it's a popup or a modal. I'm using `bootstrap`'s modal plugin, which captures key events because of a "focus-lock thing", so the only way I can make it transparent is that I redirect these events to my *real* menu.

Comment: You will need to call `stopPropagation()` on the inner event to stop it bubbling up and calling itself again - that's the cause of your problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have that check for the `target` exactly for this, but since jQuery doesn't *fix* the target when re-triggering the event, it will still cause infinite call. Actually I don't want to stop propagation for other reasons.

Comment: `I could of course manually "hack" the target` - seems like you're doing some pretty liberal hacking here anyway. Maybe instead of triggering the event on the inner target, you could just call the function that triggering the even on the inner target calls.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach the event handler onto the outer and specify a selector to use to match the event:

```
$('#outer').on('keydown', '#inner', event => {
  /* this is executed when #inner is clicked */
});
```

If you really want to use trigger, you could put it in a setTimeout:

```
$('#outer').on('keydown', event => {
  if (yourCondition) {
    setTimeout(() => $('#inner').trigger(event), 0);
  }
});
```

Comment: 0 setTimeout is executed in the next event loop, but you're right, it is not nice and the first solution is what I would suggest, the second is just there so if for some reason trigger has to be called, setTimeout will solve the call stack size issue. It will still bubble up which means that it has the chance of freezing the browser tab :)

Comment: Won't it still cause an infinite call-loop? It just won't be in the same stack.

Comment: Yes, it will be an infinite loop unless somewhere you say stopPropagation. Generally redirecting an event could be done by trigger but it just doesn't make much sense to trigger an event within a component where you listen for that same event, unless you do it for reducing the number of registered event handlers in which case, the first solution should work for you.

Comment: Yes I *could* prevent infinite call-loop without stopping propagation, if the `target` was properly re-set when triggering the event again. See my answer for what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

The event will bubble up and you're right, it's the same event. This isn't a jQuery thing but actually just how javascript works. You may want to set a listener on the child element, and use preventDefault();

```js
$("#outer").on("keydown", doSomeThing);

$("#inner").on("keydown", doSomeThingElse);

function doSomeThing(e) {
}

function doSomeThingElse(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

this will allow you to separate your listeners into distinct functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I must not stop propagation or prevent default, so that's why I need the check the relation between `currentTarget` and `target`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers and comments. A few of you suggested preventing propagation of the event at the `#inner` div. I need to avoid this, I need a way where any external consumer will see this event just as it was triggered by the `#inner` element for real.

In the meantime I digged into jQuery source and found this line in `trigger`.

```
if ( !event.target ) {
    event.target = elem;
}
```

So when `jQuery` initializes the event to trigger, it only assignes the element to the `target` if the `target` is not yet specified. sure they have some good reasons for this behavior, which I cannot see at this moment.

So the best thing I could come up with is a function like this.

```
function redirectEvent(currentTarget, evt, newTarget) {
  if (currentTarget !== newTarget && !$.contains(currentTarget, newTarget)) {
    evt = $.Event(evt.type, evt);
    delete evt.target;
    $(newTarget).trigger(evt);
  }
}
```

As far as first tests go, I can't see any side-effect or drawback.